# How to recover/restore the data (records) of my MySQL database on a corrupted hard drive?

Tags: mysql, database

A few days ago my hard drive crashed (no booting anymore). On this hard drive was a MySQL installation with a database (called "db_cedar"). Meanwhile, I could connect the corrupted hard drive as a second hard drive to my computer. That means I have full access to the file system of the crashed hard drive, thus on the MySQL files and folders.

I did never a backup of my database. I know, my fault. :-(

Is there a way to recover/restore the data (records) of my database (db_cedar) or even the entire database, for example by copying particular MySQL files or folders (on the crashed hard drive) and puting these on my new hard drive with a freshly installed version of MySQL? Note: The freshly installed MySQL version on my new hard drive is exactly the same version of the MySQL version on the crashed hard drive.

I would be very happy for any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Provided the data is not corrupt, you should be able to copy the entire database directory + the my.cnf file and get back up and running.

Comment: With "my.cnf" you mean the "my.ini" file?

And where is the entire database directory? The MySQL installation is on:
"C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/".

There are different folders (e. g. the "data" folder). But I'm missing the database folder (db_cedar). But on "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/" I have found a "data" folder which include the folder "db_cedar". This folder includes different files ending with ".frm" and ".TRG". You mean this folder?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For restoring InnoDB databases, have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27832285/3247497).and have a look at taking cold backup f innodb from mysql docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.5/en/innodb-backup.html#glos_cold_backup). For MYSIAM, it is easier. As @mluebke said just copy database directory and the my.cnf (for non-windows) or my.ini for windows