# I moved my xampp folder because my Windows crashed - now I want to recover my old projects

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp, recover

I have came up with an issue.

My last Windows got crashed; all I could do was to recover my XAMPP folder in C drive, after doing so, I reinstalled a new windows and also installed xampp.

Now I want to recover my old database in the previous windows to the new one (in the new xampp).

I have moved my old mysql/data folder contents to the new one in c:/xampp/mysql/data and also moved my htdocs folder content to the new one. (c:/xampp/htdocs)

After doing so, when I try to access my projects the contents are unreadable.
there is a page like this [my crashed project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlI8b.png)
almost all of my projects are crashed somehow.

Also on some projects, when I try to load them in htdocs, mysqld.exe stops working and crashes. I'm pretty sure there's a problem with mysql, but I don't know what is it.

Some additional information that may help :

- My OS is Windows 10
- My projects are Wordpress websites
- I'm using XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2

Answer (score 1):

Before deleting xampp folder you should always export your SQL database. So that after installing xampp again you could import the database. But since you have no backup. You have no option, you have to make tables again and enter data.

There is one hope for you. Read this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680261/restore-mysql-database-folder-from-a-recovered-hard-disk)

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I didnt delete my xampp folder, I have the old xampp folder with all of the contents, I just dont have the .sql databases but I still have the mysql data in the xampp/mysql/data/ folder. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link help you resolve the issue.

https://techubber.blogspot.com/2017/06/how-to-website-from-xampp-one-computer-to-another-computer.html

Comment: Once blogspot.com is down/unreachable this answer is of no use to anyone.